# How to find Green's function of an ODE using Laplace transform.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, greens-function

> I have the problem of finding the Green's function for the problem
> $$
> u''(x)=f(x),
> $$
> with $f \in C[0,1]$, $u \in C^2[0,1]$, and $u(0)=u'(1)=0$.

First of all I can easily see that the operator is self-adjoint.

So I need to solve the problem $$
G''(x,y)=\delta (x-y).
$$

I want to solve this using the Laplace transform.

Taking the transform on both sides and solving for $G$ I get $$G(s) =\frac{e^{-ys}+G'(0)}{s^2}. $$

Taking the inverse Laplace transform I get $$G(x,y)=G'(0)x+xH(x-y)-yH(x-y)$$
where $H$ is the Heaviside function.

The problem is that I wasn't able to find $G'(0)$ since the boundary conditions are $u(0)=u'(1)=0$, there is no condition for $u'(0)$.

However I know that $G'(0)$ must be zero, since I also computed the Green's function using a different way and got as solution
$$
G(x,y)=xH(x-y)-yH(x-y).
$$

So my question is, how can I find $G'(0)$?

Comment: The command of Mathematica `GreenFunction[{u''[x], u[0] == 0, u'[1] == 0}, u[x], {x, 0, 1}, y]` results in $-y \theta (x-y)-x \theta (y-x)$ which differs from yours.

Comment: What does $\theta$ stand for?

Comment: Treat $y$ as a parameter for a moment. Then you want $g''_y(x)=\delta_y(x),g_y(0)=0,g_y'(1)=0$. So $s^2 G_y(s)-g_y'(0)=e^{-sy}$ and so $G_y(s)=\frac{e^{-sy}+G_y'(0)}{s^2}$. Inverting that gives $g_y'(0) x + (x-y) H(x-y)$ in your notation. Now $y \in (0,1)$, so in a small enough neighborhood of $x=1$ the Heaviside function becomes $H(1-y)=1$ no matter what $y$ is. So $g_y'(1)=g_y'(0)+1$ and so $g_y'(0)=-1$, so I end up with $g_y(x)=-x+(x-y) H(x-y)$, or in other words $\begin{cases} -x & x<y \\ -y & x>y \end{cases}$.

Comment: This seems to agree with what user64494 got with Mathematica (which uses $\theta$ to denote the Heaviside function, which is a fairly common convention).

Comment: Note that this "shooting method" problem, where the Laplace transform is expressed in terms of the unknown $g'_y(0)$ and you have to solve for it after inverting, is quite generic for using the Laplace transform for anything except IVPs.